# Is separate EFI boot partition required?

Tags: boot, uefi, partitioning, mbr, gpt

In the past with BIOS, I've never created a separate partition for the bootloader.

My question is, if i wish to use UEFI, is a separate boot partition a requirement?

PS, I've tried without and it doesn't seem to work. Hence this question.

Answer (score 29):

Yes, a separate EFI partition (FAT32 formated) small partition is always required if using UEFI mode. ~300MB should be enough for multi-boot but ~550MB is preferable.

The ESP - EFI System Partiton - should not be confused with `/boot` (not required for most Ubuntu installations) and is a standard requirement.

Additional info:

[Linux on UEFI: A Quick Installation Guide](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

[UEFI boot: how does that actually work](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)

Comment: I will have only one OS. Is there absolutely no way that I can proceed without a separate boot partition for UEFI?

Comment: Again, it's a requirement, even for single OS (which one doesn't matter). What's your problem in having that partition? Really?

Comment: I'm thinking that if its possible for BIOS, then why can it not be done for UEFI.

Comment: It's not for you to decide that, it's an industry standard. If you don't have ESP you cannot install in UEFI mode, period.

Comment: Do not confuse the ESP - efi system partition which is required for UEFI boot with a Linux /boot partition. Most installs do not need the /boot partition. But if using gpt you need the ESP for UEFI boot or a bios_grub partition for BIOS boot. Or you can use the 35 year old but well known BIOS/MBR configuration. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: To reiterate and elaborate on oldfred's comment, see [Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/) or [my page on installing Linux on EFI systems.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/) Neither page really emphasizes the difference between `/boot` and the ESP, but both describe the EFI boot process and EFI needs in a way that should be helpful.

Comment: @sudoman - I must have been distracted when I accepted you unacceptable edit. There is no middle ground here. The answer to your answer is an unquestionable "Yes, always". If you don't like how things are regarding UEFI requirements, take it to whoever invented UEFI, but please do not muddy the waters here.

Comment: @CelticWarrior read oldfreds comment above. That's what i was going for.

Comment: @sudoman I know but that's besides the point of the question. Complementary but doesn't change the fundamentals.

Comment: In all honesty, It wasn't your answer that helped me. Rather it was what @oldfred commented that did. That is why I edited your answer, to include what oldfred was saying. I'll consider writing my own answer if you aren't willing to accept an improvement.

Comment: @sudoman you should. And please do not write an answer that personally references CW either. This is not a forum. https://askubuntu.com/help - for more information.

Comment: @oldfred Hello, its been a while, could you write an answer for this question based on what you wrote in your comment. I'd like to accept it as the answer as that is what actually helped me. Thanks!

Comment: The edited answer above is all I could write, so I will just leave it. And Rod Smith's comments improved it.