# Least Number of Manual Partitions during Ubuntu (Say 18.04) (Standalone, not along with any other OS) Installation

Tags: boot, partitioning

I was told to create so many partitions (Manual Partition) Eg. root, home, boot, swap, var...etc. in installation of Ubuntu

Please tell me how many (least) partitions are required to install Ubuntu

I guess minimum two partitions are required 1- for Root and 2- For your Data storage.

Comment: The release of Ubuntu matters here, older releases cannot use swapfiles by default thus need a swap partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One. You must have a partition named `/`.

All other partitions are fluff.

- swap nowadays is a file.
- /home/ is useful for separating system and personal files
- /datapartition/ is useful for separating personal files where more than 1 user on the system would like access to these files. You can mount this when you reinstall / (and optional /home/)
- /var/ used to be a partition for SERVERS to prevent `/` from filling up. Due to large disks (TB+ in size) that got unneeded.
- A /boot/ is only required if root partition is encrypted

You also need a partition for EFI if you use it but that one is not part of Ubuntu You make that outside of Ubuntu and not during installation ( [Is separate EFI boot partition required?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/827491/is-separate-efi-boot-partition-required) )

Comment: What about /boot ? That use to be a partition too. And the UEFI stuff ?

Comment: There added :-)